# Unexpected mouse click event occurs .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, message-queue

I am new to c# .NET Compact Framework 3.5.

I am trying to prevent mouse events from eager users to queue up. This sometimes leads to unintended clicks.

What is the best way to ignore queued mouse messages on the .NET Compact Framework platform? Sadly, the code has to run on the UI thread.

I have tried: 
1. Disable window and Application.DoEvents(); then Enabled window --> it did not work.
2. I read a lot about PeekMessage() --> but could not figure out.

please recommend me resource which i can learn.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    private bool _processing;

    private void OnMousedown(....) // really depends on what you use, 
        // Click/doubleclick/Up/down - concept is the same
    {
        if (_processing)
            return;
        _processing = true;
        // do something 
        . . . . . . 

        _processing = false;
     }
. . . . .
```

you may need to do it on each control event

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried same code. The strangest thing is that sometimes it discard click event, but some case  there is an unexpected mouse click event.

Comment: @Tuvi Remember that form is also control and you can also try using lock

Comment: First of all thank you for your advise. The problem was my window consists of number of components and some controls are related with each others that is why above method was bit complicate to handle.

Answer (score 3):

Thank  Google and others, I used PeekMessage()..I will post a code (may it will help some one.)

```
    private const uint PM_REMOVE = 0x1;
    private const uint WM_MOUSEFIRST = 0x0200;
    private const uint WM_MOUSELAST = 0x0209;
    private const uint WM_QUIT = 0x0012;
    private struct Message
    {
        long hwnd;
        long message;
        long wParam;
        long lParam;
        long time;
        Point pt;
    }
    #if WindowsCE
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    #else
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    #endif
private extern static bool PeekMessage(out Message Msg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax, uint wRemoveMsg);
  public void ClearMouseClickQueue()
        {  Message msg;
    while (PeekMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, WM_MOUSEFIRST,WM_MOUSELAST, 1) != false){ }}
```

That it was...cool right...

Answer (score 2):

Another option to disable touch input is to use TouchRegisterWindow and TouchUnregisterWindow with a small window (element). That can be used to disable all clicks in a current dialog without having to disable all elements one by one.

Details at http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/09/24/windows-mobile-disable-touch-input/

Comment: Thank you so much for your recommendation.

Comment: This was a an interesting approach.  Can you tell me if you used this on the other CE and WinMo / WEH operating systems.  The comments in the article mention it not being available across the board.

Comment: TouchRegisterWindow is part of Windows Mobile OS since ???? (at least Windows Mobile 2005) and so can be used on any certified Windows Mobile 5/6 device.

Comment: @tcarvin I read an article. But  problem was solved by above solution. I did not use third part library. Because system runs in SD card... therefore i was little afraid of lack of memory or some related problem. The biggest problem is that still I am not an expert...  Thank you so much...